# Scala flatMap'd Future behaviour

Tags: scala, future

Futures seem to good to be true, in a way. They trivialize multithreading in their sheer ease of use, and embracing them has made me enjoy Scala coding more.

That said, I've found a hole in my understanding. Say we have a function:

```
def foo: Future[C] = {
  val f: Future[A] = ...
  val g: A => Future[B] = ...  // DB access maybe. Don't care about return type.
  val h: A => Future[C] = ...

  // Monads are great.
  f.flatMap { a =>
    g(a)  // Eval time? Return type?
    h(a)
  } 
}
```

**Questions**

1. `foo` and `h` don't depend on the return value of `g`. Will they complete even if `g` hasn't? That is, would `foo.map(...)` yield the value of `h(a)` if `g` hasn't finished?
2. What is the return type of `g` here? Is it handled as `Unit`, since it's ignored?

Answer (score 4):

the return type of `g` is clearly denoted as `Future[B]`, That doesn't change. You are correct to recognize that this value is being thrown away. side-effects performed in the Future[B] will still happen, and they will happen regardless of what happens in the future created by `h`.

What I would do, in order to highlight this is to write this in a way which is computationally equivalent, but makes more clear that these things are happening:

```
f.foreach(g)
f.flatMap(h)
```

Whenever you see `foreach` it should trigger "side effects must be happening", which is an important thing for the reader to keep track of.

Answer (score 3):

I voted up Stew's answer but will add that if you do care if `g` failed then another way of writing this is:

```
 f.flatMap{
   val ga = g(a)
   val ha = h(a)

   for{
     _ <- ga
     out <- ha
   } yield out
 }
```

That will run both `h` and `g` in different threads without skipping `h` but preserve the error from `g`.

Comment: In my original code, what would happen if `g(a)` threw an Exception?

Comment: The result would be a failed future with that exception

Comment: Would `h(a)` still run?

Comment: Yup, it would but only because I didn't nest the function invocation within the for-comp.

Comment: So the actual "firing" of the Future occurs when you bind it to a `val` then.

Comment: @fosskers Yes, exactly.